# eth_newFilter call to QuickNode not returning any data

Tags: http, ethereum

I am making an `eth_newFilter` call on the QuickNode API but when I call `eth_getFilterChanges` nothing is returned.  Can anyone spot the issue?

https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/eth_newFilter

https://www.quicknode.com/docs/ethereum/eth_getFilterChanges

```
{
    "method": "eth_newFilter",
    "id": 1,
    "params": [
        {
            "toBlock": "0x1123e09",
            "fromBlock": "0x1122971",
            "topics": [
                "0xd78ad95fa46c994b6551d0da85fc275fe613ce37657fb8d5e3d130840159d822"
            ],
            "address": [
            ]
        }
    ],
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}

{
    "method": "eth_getFilterChanges",
    "id": 1,
    "params": [
        "0x55346da29fd068a06745ec13a46dd5ea"
    ],
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```